# Add item ONLY to the primairy navigation

Tags: menus, navigation, homepage

this code add the proper "home" to navigation... what i try to get is add home to ANLY the primairy navigation, how do i target the "main" only

```
function new_nav_menu_items($items) {
    $lang = qtrans_getLanguage();

    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'items_wrap' => '<ul><li id="item-id"><a href="$current_url">Home</a></li>%3$s</ul>' ) );
    $homelink = '<li class="home"><a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . $lang. '">' . __('Home') . '</a></li>';
    $items = $homelink . $items;

    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did find my answer here : http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-items-to-specific-wordpress-menus/

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item', 10, 2 );
function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {
    if (is_single() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $items .= '<li>Show whatever</li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```